# "The given reader is incompatible with the current materializer. Create a different materializer for this reader."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm getting the abovementioned error message, and I'm hoping that someone can translate the thing for me.  The only references I've found online in a bit of searching are quotes from code blocks without explanation.  They look like they're related, but they don't actually offer any help in figuring out what's going on.

background: I'm trying to maintain a chunk of legacy code in an mvc2/C#/EF/SQL stack, which uses these materializers (and, presumably, readers) as a way to communicate with the database.  I have essentially no understanding of how materializers work beyond the "oh, that seems sort of like it does something like this" that you get just from a read-through of the code itself.  I had to make some changes to the database on one of the table/object sets that used a materializer.  I adjusted the materializer appropriately (as far as I can tell), cheating off of the existing code heavily to add equivalent lines for the columns/properties that were added, and removing lines for those that were removed.  I also commented out a function in the c# class called TryParse, because as far as I could tell, nothing used it, and we're attempting to cut down on the cruft a bit.  It now appears to fail some, but not all, of the time when the thing is used.  I really do not know whether it was failing like this before my changes or not.

I don't need an answer of what exactly is going on - I have a suspicion that that would take way too much commenting of code blocks and whatnot.  Mostly, I'm hoping that someone can give me a general pointer or two of the "ah, this error message generally means that" variety, so that I'm not flying completely blind (though if anyone is able to come up with more than that based on the information I've given, that would be great).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is from [EFExtensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions). The source indicates that this error is thrown when the shape (field count and field names) of a record in a reader doesn't match the shape the materializer expects.

(A materializer is just something that makes *object instances* out of *something else*, in this case data read by a reader)

It's not immediately clear to me from the EFExtensions source how this can happen in the 'normal' case, as it looks like the expected shape is inferred from the *first* record read, and then all subsequent records are checked against that. Obviously for a normal `IDataReader`, all the records will have the same shape.

However, it sounds like you might have custom materializers at work (possibly inheriting from the EFExtensions ones, hence why you're getting their error messages), in which case the answer might lie in your materializer code.

Comment: Thank you.  Looking into this now.